# Convert qiskit circuit to numpy function with possibly free parameters

Tags: qiskit

Is it possible to convert a qiskit circuit into a numpy function, such that the resulting function can be used for further analysis with, possibly, implicit parameters?

Answer (score 3):

This is currently not possible by using Qiskit directly but I developed the [`qiskit-symb`](https://github.com/SimoneGasperini/qiskit-symb) package (as part of the official [Qiskit Ecosystem](https://qiskit.org/ecosystem)) on top of `qiskit-terra` itself to allow something very similar to what you need.

Check out the README file in the `qiskit-symb` project repository ([this section](https://github.com/SimoneGasperini/qiskit-symb#lambdify-a-qiskit-circuit), in particular). Feel free to contact me if you have questions or you need any support.

Comment: Ah! Good to have the developer here. Yes, I saw your question here in the stack, but it seems that it doesn't "accept" controlled unitary gates: `TypeError: CUGate.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'ctrl_qubits'`.

This is kind of strange, as my circuit is fine, even plotting the circuit as `circuit.draw('mpl')
` with `Parameters`.

Comment: This error is for the first part of the package, when I do `op = Operator(circuit); op.to_sympy()`. If I use `statevec = Statevector(circuit).to_lambda()` then the kernel keeps running indefinitely.

Comment: Uh ok, I'm sorry about that! The problem here should be related to a well known issue in Qiskit about parameters assignment for the `CUGate` (see [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/7326)) and I guess the error is then not handled properly by `qiskit-symb`. Could you please open an issue on the GitHub repo specifying your Python and `qiskit-terra` version and showing a minimal piece of code raising the error? I could take a look into it immediately.

Comment: Of course, thanks a lot!!